# wygwam error after move of server

Tags: wygwam, php

I am new to ExpressEngine. One of my clients has a website built in EE by another developer.  We have just moved the site to a new server, and now we are getting the following errors, if anyone can help that will be great.

Current version is ExpressionEngine 2.5.3

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: 8192
Message: Non-static method Wygwam_helper::replace_page_tags() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context
Filename: wygwam/ft.wygwam.php
Line Number: 562

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: 8192
Message: Non-static method Wygwam_helper::replace_page_tags() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context
Filename: wygwam/ft.wygwam.php
Line Number: 562

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: 8192
Message: Non-static method Wygwam_helper::replace_page_tags() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context
Filename: wygwam/ft.wygwam.php
Line Number: 562

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: 8192
Message: Non-static method Wygwam_helper::replace_page_tags() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context
Filename: wygwam/ft.wygwam.php
Line Number: 562

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: 8192
Message: Non-static method Wygwam_helper::replace_page_tags() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context
Filename: wygwam/ft.wygwam.php
Line Number: 562

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: 8192
Message: Non-static method Wygwam_helper::replace_page_tags() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context
Filename: wygwam/ft.wygwam.php
Line Number: 562

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: 8192
Message: Non-static method Trunchtml::usage() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context
Filename: trunchtml/pi.trunchtml.php
Line Number: 37

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/affinityassetfin/public_html/system/codeigniter/system/core/Exceptions.php:170)
Filename: core/Common.php
Line Number: 409

Many thanks
Shuka

Comment: What version of wygwam do you have installed?

Answer (score 1):

This is probably being caused by the new server running a newer version of php: I would start by checking what version the old and new server have.

If they are different, you can either try to revert the new server back to the version on the original server, or update the EE installation to a newer version.

If you go for updating EE, look in the [EE2 version changelog](https://docs.expressionengine.com/v2/about/changelog.html) for the version you need to update to for compatibility.

Big milestones:

- php 5.2.4 - EE 2.6.0
- php 5.3.0 - EE 2.10.3
- php 7.0 - EE 2.11.0
- php 7.1 - EE 2.11.9 (the final version)

As you update through EE2 versions you probably will also need to update some of the installed add-ons.

HTH